# Преобразование формата даты

Tags: регулярные-выражения, дата, javascript

Здравствуйте. Может мне кто - нибудь помочь сделать регулярку преобразование вот такой даты  1336337880000 в вот такую May 6, 2012 5:00:00. Ну или в цифровое, но с разделителями?

В ответе ниже я ответ на вопрос не нашел, можете что-то посоветовать?

Comment: [Date][1]


  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/datetime-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var date = new Date` (сюда передаете вашу временную метку);
Потом делаете так: `date.getMonth` что бы получить название нужного месяца забиваете индексированный массив названиями месяцев. Функция их возвращает 0 - 11. Потом `date.getDate()`, потом `date.getHours()`, `date.getMinutes()`, `date.getSeconds()` потом все эти значения в одну строку превращаете с помощью конкатенации и выводите!